# How to make a flat stomach within a month

Tags: body-fat, bellyfat, stomach

This is my 1st question in this site.I work in an IT company and as you all know no physical work at all.I sit almost 11-12 hours a day and hence my stomach has been grown up similar like the image given.

When I was in school I used to flat stomach and abes also as I was going to gym.But now after working in company I left going to gym due to lack of time.Within a year My stomach has grown up.

Please suggest some exercises that can be done at home

I saw some videos in youtube and doing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQF2jzZwlC8)

Is it possible to make flat stomach within a month?If yes please suggest me exercises and diets as well

Comment: Whats the restriction on the time frame? Why a month?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am a senior student in an accredited University in Florida in an exercise physiology program. Trust me when I say this, ABS ARE MADE IN THE KITCHEN. Contrastingly, a majority of the population believe that they dont possess abdominal muscularity, but in fact we do. How else is our lumbar spinal column supported throughout anterior sagittal motion? Lets say our hand is encompassed by this huge ball of candle wax. You know your hand is there, so in order to reveal it, you must melt the wax. You technically have a ripped six pack at this very moment, it is just hidden. The question we all should be asking ourselves in your situation is....how do we reveal them? Well, first we must understand that there is a layer of adiposity (fat) on top of our abdominal structure. Secondly, you must realize how to manipulate the thickness of that layer of adiposity. Ultimately, fat accumulation comes down to caloric intake. If you are intaking more calories as you burn through out the day, you gain adipose and vice versa. It doesnt really matter what you eat, but the understanding that this principle is as simple as adding and subtracting.

Here is my proposed solution. Start by calculating your basal metabolic rate. This value can be found on countless sites by simply inputting a couple of height, weight, and level of activity values. this will give you the amount of calories that you burn in a day given your physiologic background and activity level. Then learn how to count your calories and eat at a 500 calorie defecit each day for healthy fat loss until you have reached your dream. My professor always emphasizes that it is significantly easier to achieve fat loss through diet alone.  It is easier to simply not eat 600 calories than to spend 3 hours in a gym burning 600 calories. Although a combo of exercise and diet will get you there faster. But if you maintain your current eating habits and just use exercise to achieve abdominal visuality, then most likely it will take much longer and be that much harder to achieve. But the most important aspect of course is motivation and perseverance, which many people are challenged with.  Well .... hope you found what you were looking for in a general sense and good luck on your journey

Comment: Abs are made in the kitchen? I would think that abs are made in the gym with a weight-training regime to target abdominal hypertrophy. They might be revealed by a good diet, but nothing in the kitchen *makes* abs.

Comment: +1 I buy it. Even the "biggest" abs aren't visible with fat over them, and less-developed abs can still show definition if the layer of fit is thin enough.

Comment: Sorry didnt mean for the "abs made in the kitchen" to be taken literrally. I was indirectly referring to the fact that if you do not eat at a caloric defecit, then it does not matter how hard you exercise, you wont see your abs. Have you ever seen those strong man competitions? I guarantee 90 percent of them do not have visible abs, since strength gains are directly correlated with caloric excess. You must eat more to become stronger. What about bodybuilders? their workout regimen revolves around strict hypertrophy 8-12 reps/set in season, off season bulking 3-5 reps/set, and diet adjustments

Comment: To greg, exactly. Ive always had a friend thats skinny as a twig, he ate very poorly with extreme unhealthy caloric defecit, yet this habit of his did reveal his abdominal muscles,  although not as much mass as some would prefer due to malnutrition, they were still visible. Some days he would only eat 2 bowls of cereal and it was difficult for him to stuff in more food. I think he had an abnormally small stomach or something